# Python Pandas-Key error on Datetime column: is a Datetime Index not a callable column for slicing?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, slice, python-datetime

I need to select and write out to a .csv a selected date range from a dataframe. When I attempt the date selection I get:

```
KeyError: 'Date'
```

My understanding is that a key error results when Python cannot find something. But when I run df.index, I see my "error" column ('Date') is there, listed as a Datetime index. So my first question is: Is a DatetimeIndex not callable as an actual column for use in slicing?

How can I continue to have my date column as a Datetime Index so I can resample, as well as use that column to select a date range? I am trying to programmatically select rows of data between the start and end of (US) Daylight Savings Time.

```
My code looks like this:


`# This is a Test to slice out DST.

import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from pytz import all_timezones

#use these columns
colnames=['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low','Close','Volume'] 

#Read in the "header added" historical data
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/aiki/Desktop/Pandas Convert/A6_continuous_UNadjusted_1min.txt",names=colnames, header=0,index_col='Date',parse_dates=True)

#Make this naive NY data TZ aware
df = df.tz_localize('America/New_York')

df.index
```

DatetimeIndex(['2006-03-24 11:59:00-05:00', '2006-03-24 12:00:00-05:00',
'2006-03-24 12:01:00-05:00', '2006-03-24 12:02:00-05:00',
'2006-03-24 12:03:00-05:00', '2006-03-24 12:04:00-05:00',
'2006-03-24 12:08:00-05:00', '2006-03-24 12:09:00-05:00',
'2006-03-24 12:10:00-05:00', '2006-03-24 12:11:00-05:00',
...
'2022-11-04 16:50:00-04:00', '2022-11-04 16:51:00-04:00',
'2022-11-04 16:52:00-04:00', '2022-11-04 16:53:00-04:00',
'2022-11-04 16:54:00-04:00', '2022-11-04 16:55:00-04:00',
'2022-11-04 16:56:00-04:00', '2022-11-04 16:57:00-04:00',
'2022-11-04 16:58:00-04:00', '2022-11-04 16:59:00-04:00'],
dtype='datetime64[ns, America/New_York]', name='Date', length=5307718, freq=None)

```
`


But when I run df.columns I get:

`
```

Index(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'], dtype='object')

```
`

And if I try to select a date range using this code (which itself may not be the right way to proceed):

`start_day = '2022-03-13 16:00:00-0500'
end_day = '2022-11-04 14:00:00-0500'


# Convert start / end dates to datetime
start_day = pd.to_datetime(start_day)
end_day = pd.to_datetime(end_day)

df[df['Date'].between(start_day, end_day)]`


I get the:
```

KeyError: 'Date'

```
----------


I have now removed index_col='Date' per steflbert's comment below. 

When I run df.columns, I get:


    Index(['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'], dtype='object')


So I now have a column recongnizable as such - thank you.


But when I run: 

    start_day = '2022-03-13 16:00:00-0500'
    end_day = '2022-11-04 14:00:00-0500'
    
    
    # Convert start / end dates to datetime
    start_day = pd.to_datetime(start_day)
    end_day = pd.to_datetime(end_day)
    
    df[df['Date'].between(start_day, end_day)]

I now get the error: TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'




I am trying to select a date range of this dataframe- is there some better way to do this, please?
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Date as an index, so you can't access it like a column. Try removing `index_col='Date'` when reading the csv, then the date will be a normal column.

Comment: Thank you @steflbert: I understand you to mean that a column used as an idex cannot be accessed as a column for slicing. Is that correct, please?

Also, I have followed your lead and removed that code in the body above, but I now have another error. Have you any thoughts, please?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by using a columns for slicing. If you want to select rows according to one column, for example if you want dates in a certain range, you can use a normal comaprinson with `<` or `>` on the column and use it as a mask.